# AWS EIP To Load balancer confuses cert store on XP

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2, glassfish

I have deployed 'legacy' xp boxes using a .net app to access soap based services running out of AWS using SSL.

Initially I was serving these off of a Elastic IP (re static) address, and all was well in the world.  The service, (Glassfish based), was properly sending the cert, and the xp boxes were happy campers and using the cert.  The domain was foo.bar.com  and the cert is a godaddy wildcard cert *.bar.com.  I did this using a Route 53 zone with an 'A' record.  IE was able to connect from the xp box.. no problemo.. to the Glassfish instance using https://foo.bar.com.

I then disassociated the EIP, and setup a AWS load balancer with the sub domain pointed at the load balancer using a CNAME rec in Route 53.

When I went to IE on XP I found that IE was throwing cert errors 'unable to establish trust" or some such.  When I looked at the godaddy cert on the xp box there was no trust chain.

So .. what in the world would cause a legacy version of XP to lose the trust chain just by pointing the DNS name at a load balancer versus a static IP.

I did install the same cert in the load balancer as is installed in Glassfish, and verified that the trust chain and certs from both were the same using Win 7 and IE on a unrelated box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably you did not install the intermediary certificates on the ELB.

When adding certificate + private key to the ELB you'll see another text box named'Certificate Chain'.
If you have multiple intermediary certificates you'll have to append all of them there. Order matters!

Comment: I apologize for not responding here.. Actually the intermediate cert is installed.  We have one customer that has this problem out of 100 or so ...I think it has something to do with their firewall or proxy.  Many of the customers are running on similarly configured XP boxes without issue.  If I figure it out will repost here.